# Negative mass? How it works and can it travel the speed of light?

Tags: mass

If something with mass can't travel at the speed of light, how about an object with negative mass (hypothetically). Can somebody describe how negative mass works and what it is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is opinion based and regards a hypothetical situation and thus lies outside the scope of mainstream physics discussions.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia entry on *negative mass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass)?

Answer (score 1):

Mass appears in many formulas and sometimes what you think is caused by mass is actually caused by energy.

For instance gravity is caused by energy, not by mass. And in relativity we find out energy satisfies $E=+\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$ so even if mass were negative, energy would still be positive.

And you might think momentum is proportional to mass and velocity, but again in relativity we find $p=+\sqrt{E^2/c^2-m^2c^2}.$ Or if you want to include velocity, $p=vE/c^2.$

And this leads to a huge fact about Relativity. There are lots of things that used to be equal to each other that we find out aren't really equal. For instance does $F=ma$ or does $F=dp/dt$? They aren't equal in relativity so they can't both be correct! (Or should it be $F=dp/d\tau$?)

And what this means is that if one person is imagining some equations and wonders what happens if you change a sign and a different person is imaging a different (but equivalent) equation and wonders what happens if you change a sign they might get different results because the two equations might only be equivalent when mass was not negative.

So the kinds of things you could ask are more basic. Like what if momentum and velocity could point in opposite directions (but then energy would be still be positive). Or what if energy could be negative. Or both. Lots of questions, lots of different answers.

It's important to consider them in the sense of looking for good reasons to forbid it or to find out what predictions they imply so you can look for evidence (evidence for or evidence against and some experiments are only good at looking for one of hose two types so don't jump the gun or leap to conclusions).

Comment: I consider this response very appropriate and helpful, even though it appears more as a meta-answer (to the meta-question why the OP cannot easily be answered, as it stands), than a direct answer to the OP. Therefore, from me: +1. ([YMMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YMMV), @Danu.)